# how to enable javascript in BrowserField?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I had deployed my **blackberry** app which loads html pages from resource files. The html files have javascript and jquery and i need to enable javascript as in Android.

```
BrowserField browser = new BrowserField();

add(browser);

InputStream content = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resourcesWeb/index.html");     
try {
   byte[] html = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(content);
   browser.displayContent(new String(html), "http://localhost");
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: [See this link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BrowserField-Sample-Code-Using-the-BrowserFieldConfig-class/ta-p/495716)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enabled by default, but here's how you'd force it:

```
    BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
    config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
    BrowserField browser  = new BrowserField(config);
```

Comment: i had this error The method setProperty(String, Object) in the type BrowserFieldConfig is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)

Comment: Yes, the setProperty method needs an object as second argument. Then pass it a `new Boolean(true)` instead of `true`. If still not works, try passing the string `"true"`.